# Database retreival query in Android

Tags: android, database

In my application i have 1 table layout,in that i show data from database.Actually what i did is i have 1 spinner option in my screen, the 1st time my app loads i have some 5 hardcore value and the 6th spinner option value is edit.If user selects edit from spinner, I allow the user to edit the 5 hardcore value of spinner value. I update the edited value in the spinner from which user can select 1 option and with some other entries(like price,item) user can save it in the database.This is my scenario, what I want now is to retrieve the data from database separately under each value which is selected from spinner.How can i query the database.Please help me..I think i have explained my problem clearly..I am ready to give More details.

Below is my spinner image link:

[*http://www.freeimagehosting.net/12rgk*](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/12rgk)

From which user can select 1 option,if he selects edit in that means i allowed him to edit the spinner values.

This is my database structure:

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/e2vbp

Comment: Have you done any database related stuffs in android before? if not go through this link http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/database-crud-tutorial-for-android/

Comment: Thanks Vinay Kumar j g ...I have done database related stuffs b4..But this situation is critical???thats y i posted..

Answer (score 0):

When you created your database did you make the options in your spinner the column names for your table? If you did, then you could use a query like

```
public Cursor getOptions()
{
    return db.query(Tablename,new String[] {col1,col2,col3,
            col4,col5},null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

I should point out that you might need to provide more details as your question is ambiguous.

Comment: I am not clear about your answer...Actually In table i have one column group under which the spinner value selected by user will store??

Comment: I am suggesting that you implement a database with 6 columns, one for the _id and the other 5 containing your hardcoded values. You should populate your spinner with the values from those 5 database columns. Once you do that, any changes to the hardcoded values in your spinner can be stored in the corresponding column in your database. If you prefer, you can then just update the columns whenever the user edits them, so that your table only contains one record at any time. oh and I would suggest using another table to store the users selection along with other entries (price, item, ...).